# Match outer brackets in Java too slow

Tags: java, performance

I need to select all the text between two outer brackets.  As regular expressions cannot be assured to select matching brackets, I coded the following:

```
public static String getContentBetweenCorresponding(String s, char left, char right) {
    int pos = s.indexOf(left);
    if ( pos > -1 ) {
        int start = pos;
        int openCount = 0;
        while ( pos < s.length() ) {
            char currentChar = s.charAt(pos);
            if ( currentChar == right ) {
                if ( openCount > 1 ) // if openCount == 1 then correct one 
                    openCount--;
                else
                    return s.substring(start + 1, pos);
            } else if ( currentChar == left )
                openCount++;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works.  HOWEVER IT IS INSANELY SLOW.  How can I speed things up?  This method needs 5s for the string at hand and is the bottleneck of my application.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT:
What I am trying to do is to get the text between matching brackets.

```
getContentBetweenCorresponding("bla{{{blubb}}}}}}", '{', '}')
```

should return

```
"{{blubb}}"
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do (since you claim regex is not enough). Could you show us some examples of input data and expected output?

Comment: please see edit above ...

Comment: What's the lengh of the string that takes 5s to process? Maybe moving s.length() from the while condition could help (just add int len=s.length() and then just use len inside the while condition).

Comment: Using PCRE is much more easier (and faster) `\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}`: [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tC1xU1)

Comment: @lopisan: `String.legnth` is a simple accessor, and thus trivial to begin with and then method invocation will soon be removed by the JIT in favour of direct field access.  Separately, a quick glance at the code shows the use of `subString`, which is creating new String objects all the time ... that seems unnecessary.

Comment: The string is about 5000 char long and it is a couple of openings and closings.  I will revist the regex options.  The one i tried and did not succeed getting only matching brackets was (?:" + regexLeft + ")+(.*?)(?:" + regexRight + ")

Comment: The reason I claimed regex to not be working is that after googling this quite extensively, I found forum entries saying that regex is not the way to go for matching brackets ...

Comment: Regular expressions can't count, so they cannot solve this problem. The recursive extension use in @demo's line noise is not supported by `java.util.regex`.

Comment: @dotwin not sure if it will help but could you just test performance of this version http://pastebin.com/K9QMdFU6?

Comment: @Pshemo thank you, but it didn't change much.

Comment: Why match anything? If you just want the outermost brackets, use `String.indexOf()` and `String.lastIndexOf()`. If you have to match properly, I would start questioning the problem definition: why do you have input that looks like this and that has to be processed like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look too bad. Are you sure it is this method that is causing the performance problem?

You could try a tight loop just to find the next open, close or end. Perhaps convert to a char array rather than using `charAt` (`toCharArray` or probably better `getChars`). It at least used to be the case that you would get better results with smaller methods.

In more recent versions of Java `substring` will copy the backing array, which didn't used to happen.

So here's how I would write it for performance without doing any benchmarking(!) (possibly the interface could be modified not to create a `String`, or even to take one) -

```
public static String betweenMatchedBrackets(
     String str, char open, char close
) {
    int start = str.indexOf(open);
    if (start == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    ++start;
    int strLen = str.length();
    char[] cs = new char[strLen-start]; // Assume typically much of string
    strLen.getChars(start, len, cs, 0);

    int foundLen = endingBracket(cs, open, closed);
    return foundLen != cs.length ? str.substring(start, start+foundLen) : null;
}
private static int endingBracket(char cs, char open, char closed) {
    int depth = 1;
    int i = 0;
    for (; depth != 0 && i != cs.length; ) {
        i = nextInteresting(cs, i, open, close);
        if (i != cs.length) {
            char c = cs[i];
            depth += c==open ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return int;
}
private static int nextInteresting(char[] cs, int off, char open, char close) {
    for (; off != cs.length && cs[off] != open && cs[off] != close; ++off) {
    }
    return off;
}
```

(Not benchmarked, or compiled.)

Comment: I did System.nanoTime() checks and could pin it down to the Point this method is called.  Your idea sounds promising - I will look into this right now and report back.  Also, is indexOf faster than looking at each char?  What does indexOf do internally?

Comment: Check `src.zip`. It's just a loop over the internal char array. This sort of thing used to be more important when `String` was implemented with an offset and a length instead of being an entire character array. It also has the advantage that the inner loop will have been compiled so wont need a "warm up".

Comment: @dotwin Just curious :P  what is the cause of the problem then? Coz I cannot see the obvious bottleneck either :P

Answer (score 2):

The method you have written does not have any glaring inefficiencies. My guess is the problem actually lies in one of the following:

1. You might be calling this function multiple times for the same string `s`, when you could be calling it once and storing the result.
2. You might be passing extremely large strings to this method with extremely large distance between the beginning of the string and the closing brace.

*If the distance between `{` and `}` is expected to be large for your actual inputs*, you can rewrite the method to use `indexOf` to directly find `left` and `right` instead of testing the `charAt` for each character. In this case, there would be many fewer calls to `indexOf` than calls to `charAt`, and while characters in the string between the outermost braces would be examined at least two times the internal implementation of `indexOf` may exceed the performance of what the JIT is doing with `charAt`.

Comment: The trouble with (two-arg) `indexOf` is that you need to search for two different characters. Doesn't seem like a useful approach.

Comment: Thank a lot.  Is indexOf faster than looking at each char?  What does indexOf do internally?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you need to write your own method. You can use Java regex to get strings enclosed in brackets. Sample code below will give you string in the middle of normal brackets

```
    String str = "Hello (big) world";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((\\w+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    matcher.find();

            // result below is "big"
    String result = matcher.group(1);
```

Comment: It's about nested brackets, the output should be `{{blubb}}` IMO.